# How to change the size of PopoverViewController after it was presented?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple `UITableViewController` that shows as popup from `UIBarButtonItem`, it has size equal to `number of items * height of one cell`, I want to expand the cell on tap and change popover's size accordingly, preferably with nice animation. I tried to set `preferredContentSize` in `didSelectRow` method but it doesn't do anything.

In the `ViewController` which is the popover I set

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: CGFloat(46 * actions.count) + 64)
    } set {
        super.preferredContentSize = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation for `preferredContentSize`: *"Changing the value of this property while the view controller is being displayed in a popover animates the size change"*.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had to delete overriding the property, with it changing the value in method didn't have any effect